# Updating Tkinter Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to redraw a single plot whenever the user clicks in the screen. 
Currently, the plot is draw during the first click. After that, new plots are appended to the canvas. What I would like to do is to "delete" or "clear" the first plot and redraw it or updated it with the new data.

This is the part responsible for this specific plot draw:

```
class AppGUI(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):  
        self.parent = parent
        self.initGUI()
        self.plot()


    def initGUI(self):
        self.vf_frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent, bd=1, relief=Tk.SUNKEN)
        self.vf_frame.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=True)

    def plotVF(self, u, v):
            # Canvas of VF 
            m = np.sqrt(np.power(u, 2) + np.power(v, 2))

            xrange = np.linspace(0, u.shape[1], u.shape[1]);
            yrange = np.linspace(0, u.shape[0], u.shape[0]);

            x, y = np.meshgrid(xrange, yrange)
            mag = np.hypot(u, v)
            scale = 1
            lw = scale * mag / mag.max()

            f, ax = plt.subplots()
            h = ax.streamplot(x, y, u, v, color=mag, linewidth=lw, density=3, arrowsize=1, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 70))
            ax.set_xlim(0, u.shape[1])
            ax.set_ylim(0, u.shape[0])
            ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticks([])
            #cbar = f.colorbar(h, cax=ax)
            #cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=5) 

            c = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.vf_frame)
            c.show()
            c.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
```

Do I have to do `f` and `ax` attributes of my class to achieve this result? To make it clear, `plotVF` is updated by other methods.

PS: I can't also show the color bar with the commented lines. It says `'Streamplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two different functions, one to initiate the plot, the other to update it.

```
def initplot(self):
    f, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    c = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.vf_frame)
    c.show()
    c.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill="both", expand=True) 

def update(self, u, v):
    self.ax.clear() # clear the previous plot
    ...
    h = self.ax.streamplot(...)
    self.ax.set_xlim(0, u.shape[1])
    ...
```